# Excel closed unexpectedly when running VBA Macros (But only sometimes)

Tags: vba, excel

I am wondering if there are any experts that can have a look and advise what I am doing wrong with the codes below. I've adapted and modified the codes from TheSpreadsheetGuru which basically opens up all the Excel spreadsheets in a given folder and copy/paste the information into the master spreadsheet.

If I open my master spreadsheet and run the macro it actually works fine. However, if I clear the contents in the master spreadsheet first or run the macro more than once then Excel would just shut itself down - I can't see anything that's obviously wrong with the codes so would appreciate any help if you can tell me what I am doing wrong

Thanks in advance

```
Sub SI_Report() 
'PURPOSE: To copy strategic initiatives report into the master table
'SOURCE: Codes here are modified based on codes obtained from TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Check = MsgBox("This will copy all the strategic initiatives from spreadsheets stored in a folder you will now choose, are you sure?", vbOKCancel) 

If Check = vbOK Then 

Dim wb As Workbook 
Dim myPath As String 
Dim myFile As String 
Dim myExtension As String 
Dim FldrPicker As FileDialog 

 'Optimise Macro Speed
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 
Application.EnableEvents = False 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual 
Application.DisplayAlerts = False 

 'Retrieve Target Folder Path From User
Set FldrPicker = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker) 

With FldrPicker 
    .Title = "Select A Target Folder" 
    .AllowMultiSelect = False 
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode 
    myPath = .SelectedItems(1) & "\" 
End With 

 'In Case of Cancel
NextCode: 
myPath = myPath 
If myPath = "" Then GoTo ResetSettings 

 'Target File Extension
myExtension = "*.xls*" 

 'Target Path with Ending Extention
myFile = Dir(myPath & myExtension) 

 ' Clear contents first
Windows("Strategic Initiatives Master.xlsm").Activate 
Sheets("Strategic Initiatives").Select 
Range("A2:W201").Select 
Selection.ClearContents 

 'Loop through each Excel file in folder
Do While myFile <> "" 
     'Set variable equal to opened workbook
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=myPath & myFile, UpdateLinks:=0) 

     'Ensure Workbook has opened before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents 

     'Copy data
    wb.Sheets("Strategic Initiatives").Select 
    Range("A2", Range("W2").End(xlDown)).Select 
    Selection.Copy 

     'Paste data
    Windows("Strategic Initiatives Master.xlsm").Activate 
    Sheets("Strategic Initiatives").Select 
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select 
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _ 
    :=False, Transpose:=False 

     'Close Workbook without Saving
    wb.Close SaveChanges:=False 

     'Ensure Workbook has closed before moving on to next line of code
    DoEvents 

     'Get next file name
    myFile = Dir 
Loop 

Sheets("Instruction").Select 

ResetSettings: 
 'Reset Macro Optimisation Settings
Application.EnableEvents = True 
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic 
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 
Application.DisplayAlerts = True 

Else: Exit Sub 
End If 
End Sub
```

Comment: step through your code (press F8 repeatedly to jump from one statement to the following) and see where it errors out. you might also want to comment `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` out and let possible warnings pop out and help you

Comment: hi there, thanks for your reply. I've tried your suggestion and turned the display alert on and it error'd out after I picked the folder where the files are. It went straight into the "MS excel has stopped working" alert without any information that could help me to identify where it goes wrong... if you have any other suggestions that would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: What is the last statement correctly executed, i.e. the one before the yellow highlighted one that errors out at pressing F8?

Comment: hi there, thanks again for your reply. `If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode` is the one that brings up the folder picker, which runs successfully the first time, and error'd out the second run so `.AllowMultiSelect = False` is the last statement successfully executed, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Option Explicit to make sure all the variables have been declared